# How to bypass unique ID and reference child nodes

Tags: firebase, angularfire

My firbase database looks like this:

```
app
   users
       -gn4t9u4ut304u9g4
            email
            uid
```

How do I reference email and uid? When I try this:

```
        $rootScope.dashtype.child('users').orderByChild('uid').equalTo($rootScope.auth.uid).on('value', function(snapshot){
            $rootScope.user = snapshot.val();
            console.log($rootScope.user);
        })
```

I get the correct object, but with the unique id as root:

```
Object {-JvaZVrWGvJis0AYocBa: Object}
```

And because this is a dynamic property, I don't know how to reference the child objects. I just want to be able to access the user fields like this: $rootScope.user.email etc.

Comment: '-gn4t9u4ut304u9g4' is not the uid. It is the unique ID that Firebase  automatically creates when you push something. It is because of this I don't now how to reference the user fields.

Comment: My original comment was half a thought and accidentally posted - it has been removed. Since you know the uid of the user you want ($rootScope.auth.uid), you may want to consider using the uid as the node name for each user. There are a couple of benefits in that it will simplify your above code as the user node can be directly read with something like like: var ref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL + '/users/' + authUser.uid).  Also, it may make writing security rules easier as a variable like $user_id can be used to refer to each node name (the uid).

Comment: @Jay Yes, this is what I want, but the problem is that the Firebase ID (Timestamp) is automatically created as a root for my userdata. So by doing this as you suggest, it would still get in the way like this: FIREBASE_URL + '/users/*FirebaseID*/' + authUser.uid). If there only was a way to disable the Timestamp when doing a Push call.

Comment: Please read: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/user-auth.html#section-storing to see how to store users by their `uid`. Hint: calling `push()` will generate a push id and store the object under that id, calling `set()` will store the object in that place. So `ref.child(useruid).set(user)`. But as said: read the docs, they explain it better than I can in a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're requesting a value, you get a list of users as a result. It may only be one user, but it's still a list of one.

You will have to loop over the snapshot, to get to the child node:

```
$rootScope.dashtype.child('users').orderByChild('uid').equalTo($rootScope.auth.uid).on('value', function(snapshot){
    snapshot.forEach(function(userSnapshot) {
        $rootScope.user = userSnapshot.val();
        console.log($rootScope.user);
    });
});
```

Since there's only a single user in the list, the loop for execute just once.

You are mixing regular Firebase JavaScript with AngularFire here. This means that you will need to inform AngularJS that you updated the scope, so that it will rerender the view:

```
$rootScope.dashtype.child('users').orderByChild('uid').equalTo($rootScope.auth.uid).on('value', function(snapshot){
    snapshot.forEach(function(userSnapshot) {
        $timeout(function() {
            $rootScope.user = userSnapshot.val();
            console.log($rootScope.user);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: This works. Thanks. But it just seems SO excessive for the task I want to preform. If it weren't for the stupid Firebase ID I could just do this: $rootScope.user = new Firebase("https://dashtype.firebaseio.com/users/uid");

Comment: Why are you storing the users under a push id then? I'm pretty sure the examples in the Firebase documentation store users by their `uid`. https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/user-auth.html#section-storing (Jay said the same in his comment btw)

Comment: Good question! I didn't think I could have multiple objects under 'users' if I used set(), and therefore had to use push(). Intuitively I thought of set() and push() as a String and Array in Javascript, but this mental model doesn't quite fit. It should have been explained better in the docs for stupid folks like me.