# Angularfire 2.1 - How to access auto-generated ID for users (or how to make my UID the first node for each user)

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, angularfire

Disclaimer, I am trying to self-teach myself development. I am building a hybrid mobile app using Ionic 1 and now Firebase 3 for my database and authentication.

For my scenario, in short, I'm trying to display a list of 'friends' for the user that is currently logged in.  Here is the current data structure I have (the relevant part anyway):

Data Structure

[image: Data Structure]

I have a line of code that does return me what I want:

```
var friends = $firebaseArray(ref.child('users').child('-KXcxMXkKs46Xv4-JUgW').child('friends'));
```

Of course, that can't work because there is a nice little hard coded value in there.

So, I looked into how to retrieve the current UID so I could replace the hard coded value. But after running the following bit of code through, the first node under user is not the UID (it is some other auto generated value that I don't really know how it got there).  The UID is actually within the id field.

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref();
authObj = $firebaseAuth();
var firebaseUser = authObj.$getAuth();
console.log(firebaseUser.uid);
```

So, ultimately what I would love is to be able to change the data structure so that the UID is the first node under Users, but I can't seem to find documentation to do that.  I looked at this other stack thread, but it is for an outdated version and I can't seem to connect the dots.  [Other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31757307/how-to-bypass-unique-id-and-reference-child-nodes)

Though, if I can't change the structure, I still need to figure out how to access that friends node for the current user, one way or another.

Thank you in advance.  This is my first stackoverflow post, so be gentle.

**Update:**
Per Frank's comment, this is the code that I execute to create users - $add is what is creating the push id (-KXcxM...).

```
createProfile: function(uid, user) {
    var profile = {
        id: uid,
        email: user.email,
        registered_in: Date()
        // a number of other things
    };

var messagesRef = $firebaseArray(firebase.database().ref().child("users"));
messagesRef.$add(profile);
},

register: function(user) {
    return auth.$createUserWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.password)
        .then(function(firebaseUser) {
            console.log("User created with uid: " + firebaseUser.uid);
            Auth.createProfile(firebaseUser.uid, user);
            Utils.alertshow("Success!","Your user has been registered.");
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
           Utils.alertshow("Error.","Some helpful error message.");
          console.log("Error: " + error);
        });
    }
```

Comment: Those random, hardcoded values are so-called *push IDs*, which are generated when you call Firebase's `push()` method or `$add()` on a `$firebaseArray`. So somewhere in your code the users are being added to the database with either `push()` or `$add()`. Your first step to fixing the problem is finding out what code adds the users like that.

Comment: I updated my post with where I use $add.  After some more Googling, I am still not quite sure how to change this to get my desired effect.  Thoughts?  Thank you for your comment, by the way.  It does give me a new focus of research.

Comment: Add the user with this `firebase.database().ref().child("users").child(uid).set(profile)`. The `$firebaseArray()` will pick the new user up automatically.

Comment: I'm, sorry, can you be a little more explicit with me, please?  I couldn't just copy/paste your exact changes because it broke my app for some reason.  I also included my code for the register function that gets called here at the same time in case that needs to change, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of creating a `$firebaseArray` and calling `$add` on it, you can just store the user using the regular Firebase JavaScript SDK:

```
createProfile: function(uid, user) {
    var profile = {
        id: uid,
        email: user.email
    };
    firebase.database().ref().child("users").child(uid).set(profile);
}
```

Since AngularFire is built on top of the Firebase JavaScript SDK, the two interact nicely with each other. So if you have any existing `$firebaseArray` on `users` it will pick up the new profile too.

Comment: Thank you so much for being patient and very helpful!  For my learning...is there a specific area of documentation I could have honed in on a little more so that I could have avoided this by chance/

Comment: This topic (storing Firebase Authentication user profiles in the Firebase Database) is unfortunately undercovered in the documentation. We used to cover it in our [old firebase.com docs here](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/user-auth.html#section-storing). But nowadays your best bet is to do a search here on Stack Overflow for [something like this](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase-authentication%5D%5Bfirebase-database%5D+store+user+profile).